# Submit data to Sharepoint List from InfoPath or Webpage, with Active Directory Integration

Tags: list, web-part, web-services, active-directory, data

Although InfoPath seems to be on the way out, is there a best practice when it comes to submitting data from a form to a Sharepoint list using InfoPath, Webpage, or otherwise?

I'm looking to collect data from various sources/groups. Ultimately, sharing a Form or a URL to a webpage wherein the user fills out data and once its submitted, is entered into a SharePoint list that I control.

It needs to have integration with Active Directory to lookup Users for various fields.

example data may include: Topic, Region, Submitter Information (using AD), Person Assigned (using AD), Details etc.

Any tutorial on this topic or best practice would be appreciated.

We're currently running Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the suggest link. this might help you
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-data-connection-to-a-SharePoint-document-library-or-list-3233d77d-95af-4245-a124-dca2f6d5d02e

https://claytoncobb.com/2011/06/03/infopath-allowing-anonymous-users-to-submit-forms-in-sharepoint-2010/